# WinError 5 when trying to package PyQt5 application with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, github-desktop

I was experimenting with packaging my PyQt5 app using pyinstaller, and it seems to work fine except when I tried to update the executable using the `pyinstaller app.spec` command. This results in a query where it asks me if I want to remove all contents in `dist` and after accepting, it raised a few permission errors. Here is the full stack trace:

```
WARNING: The output directory "C:\Users\zedon\Documents\GitHub\2022-Project-Scam-Buster\application\dist\app" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/N)y
On your own risk, you can use the option `--noconfirm` to get rid of this question.
11156 INFO: Removing dir C:\Users\zedon\Documents\GitHub\2022-Project-Scam-Buster\application\dist\app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 446, in _make_clean_directory
    os.remove(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\zedon\\Documents\\GitHub\\2022-Project-Scam-Buster\\application\\dist\\app'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main  
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\zedon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 178, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 59, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 842, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 764, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "app.spec", line 41, in <module>
    coll = COLLECT(
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 864, in __init__
    shutil.rmtree(path)
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 740, in rmtree    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 613, in _rmtree_unsafe      
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 613, in _rmtree_unsafe      
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 613, in _rmtree_unsafe          _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 622, in _rmtree_unsafe          onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\users\zedon\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\shutil.py", line 620, in _rmtree_unsafe      
    os.rmdir(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\zedon\\Documents\\GitHub\\2022-Project-Scam-Buster\\application\\dist\\app\\PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\iconengines'
```

I can think of 2 reasons why this might happen but I do not know how to solve them, one is that the PyQt5 module has some special permissions or something that prevents it from being deleted by the program, another reason I can think is that this is in a virtual environment inside of a repo created by github desktop, and I've heard that it seems to cause some issues with editing the code inside the folders.

Can someone help to identify which issue it is, and whether there is a minimally invasive solution? I found that the problem can be adverted by deleting the dist and build folders everytime I want to update the executable, but that's not really an ideal solution.

Comment: it sounds like the executable that is saved in the `dist` folder is being actively run by your os.... make sure all forms of the program aren't running

Comment: @Alexander they are not running as far as I'm aware of, unless there somehow was something running in the background or the folder being open in VSCode counts as running

Comment: Why don't you just delete the dist folder manually?